# How does contextual menus work in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7

I've been trying to understand this for a while now, but I find the documentation either to lacking, or maybe I just don't understand what I'm looking for. Could anyone enlighten me on how to implement them?

One thing I'm trying to do is to be able to have `contextual menus` for each node in a list of nodes (loaded using `node_load_multiple`) that I'm sending along to a `theme()` function and looping through inside the `.tpl.php`

Answer (score 3):

I'll put my temporary solution here for now anyway in case it will help someone.

What I did was just creating a new theme function (?) in my module

```
$themes['contextual'] = array(
    'template' => 'contextual',
    'variables' => array('links' => array(), 'destination' => null)
);
```

Then I defined my `contextual.tpl.php`

```
<div class="contextual-links-wrapper">
    <ul class="contextual-links">
        <?php foreach($links as $url => $title): ?>
        <li>
            <?php echo l($title, $url, 
                array('query' => array('destination' => $destination))) ?>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Finally, to use it, wherever there is a need for a contextual menu, add the class `contextual-links-region` to the container div of the node (or whatever), and inside the div I use my function, for example:

```
<?php echo theme('contextual', array('destination' => 'node/'.arg(1),
    'links' => array('node/'.$somenode->nid.'/edit', t('Edit node')))); ?>
```

Comment: Is this solution working, Actually i need to use a context menu with one of my content type field.